# Problema al calificar tabla-objeto al hacer un SELECT en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo un problema con el siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT USER
    ,TO_CHAR(LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN
    ,SAILA
    ,MAX(INTENTS) INTENTS
    ,MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME
WHERE LAST_LOGIN >= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY USER
    ,TO_CHAR(LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ,SAILA
    ,INTENTS
    ,MAQ
ORDER BY SAILA;
```

Al ejecutar de esa manera se ejecuta de manera correcta sin problema alguno.

Pero al calificar los campos de la tabla y "asignar" un nombre a la tabla me manda un error, ejecuto este *query*:

```
SELECT NAME_TABLE.USER
    ,TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN
    ,NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,MAX(NAME_TABLE.INTENTS) INTENTS
    ,NAME_TABLE.MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME NAME_TABLE
WHERE NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN >= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY NAME_TABLE.USER
    ,TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ,NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,NAME_TABLE.INTENTS
    ,NAME_TABLE.MAQ
ORDER BY NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN DESC;
```

El error que arroja es:

> [Error] Execution (1: 82): ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa eso?

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: y qué mensaje de error te arroja?

Comment: [Error] Execution (1: 82): ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
Ese error.

Comment: prueba quitando `NAME_TABLE.INTENTS` del group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto solucione mi problema, gracias.

```
SELECT NAME_TABLE.USER
    ,TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN
    ,NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,MAX(NAME_TABLE.INTENTS) INTENTS
    ,NAME_TABLE.MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME NAME_TABLE
WHERE NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN >= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY NAME_TABLE.USER
    ,TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ,NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,NAME_TABLE.INTENTS
    ,NAME_TABLE.MAQ
ORDER BY NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,MAX(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN) DESC;
```

Solo tenía que agregar el `MAX()` al último campo.

Gracias.

Comment: Es bueno que hayas encontrado la solución a tu problema. En 48 horas podrás marcar tu respuesta como válida, no olvides hacerlo :D

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puedes usar un campo en las cláusulas `SELECT` o `ORDER BY` que no formen parte del `GROUP BY`, a menos que lo uses en una función de agregación como `MAX`.

En este caso, el error se debe a que usas el campo `NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN` en el `ORDER BY`. Y aunque, técnicamente, `NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN` sí está en el `GROUP BY`, en realidad no es lo mismo, porque en el `GROUP BY` estás usando la expresión `TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, de allí el error que recibes.

Aunque la solución que encontrastes de agregar el `MAX()` en el `ORDER BY` es muy sencilla y funciona bien, en mi opinión oscurece la intención de la consulta.

De estar en tu lugar, yo haría los cambios siguientes:

1. En el `GROUP BY`, cambiar `TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` por `TRUNC(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN)`, lo que cumple el mismo propósito de agrupar por fecha excluyendo la hora, pero sin tener que convertir a un tipo que no sea `date`, que en parte es lo que causa problemas en las demás partes de tu consulta.
2. En el `SELECT`, ajustar `TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN` a `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN), 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN`.
3. Usar la expresión `TRUNC(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN)` en el `ORDER BY`.

Estos cambios resultan en la consulta siguiente:

```
SELECT NAME_TABLE.USER
    ,TO_CHAR(TRUNC(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN), 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN
    ,NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,MAX(NAME_TABLE.INTENTS) INTENTS
    ,NAME_TABLE.MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME NAME_TABLE
WHERE NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN >= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY NAME_TABLE.USER
    ,TRUNC(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN)
    ,NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,NAME_TABLE.INTENTS
    ,NAME_TABLE.MAQ
ORDER BY NAME_TABLE.SAILA
    ,TRUNC(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN) DESC;
```

En mi opinión, la intención queda más clara, y tiene más sentido que la conversión de fecha a cadena (`TO_CHAR`) se limite a la claúsula `SELECT` para la presentación de los resultados.  Pero que, tanto en el `GROUP BY` como en el `ORDER BY`, todavía se maneje `LAST_LOGIN` como un tipo `DATE`.